# MySQL: How come the procedure is slower than executing the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

So i have this superduper query that finds "related articles" based on the number of tags they have in common with the original article (provided in the $id variable). I don't know if the actual query is important, but here it is Justin Case.

Now, I've never actually used procedures in a live project, but I've read they should be faster, partially because the MySQL engine doesn't need to interpret the code each time. But when i had put this same code in a procedure and called the procedure, the execution was on average about 450 times longer.

Why? Is it because it's returning multiple rows? Do procedures stink at that? Is it because i have to use an input variable in my procedure? 450 is a bunch!

```
SELECT a.id, a.image, a.title, a.excerpt, a.permalink, COUNT(rel.category_id) AS n
  FROM articles AS a
  JOIN category_relations AS rel ON rel.article_id = a.id
  JOIN categories AS c ON rel.category_id = c.id
 WHERE rel.category_id IN (SELECT category_id 
                             FROM category_relations 
                            WHERE article_id = {$id})
   AND a.id != {$id}
   AND c.type = 1
GROUP BY rel.article_id
ORDER BY n DESC, publish_date DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Code used to create the procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_related_articles;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_related_articles(IN id INT)
BEGIN
   SELECT   a.id, a.image, a.title, a.excerpt, a.permalink, COUNT(rel.category_id) AS n
   FROM     articles AS a
    JOIN  category_relations AS rel ON rel.article_id = a.id
    JOIN  categories AS c ON rel.category_id = c.id
   WHERE    rel.category_id IN ( SELECT category_id FROM category_relations WHERE article_id = id)
    AND   a.id != id
    AND   c.type = 1
   GROUP BY rel.article_id
   ORDER BY n DESC, publish_date DESC
   LIMIT    10;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you heard that they should be faster (what unit are you using to measure 450? 450 camels?). I also don't know who Justin Case is. What is the context that the stored procedure is being called? It seems like you may not be using them correctly.

Comment: Query caching occurs based on the entire query -- that includes the value(s) supplied by your PHP variable.  So as the variable changes, the query cache can't be reused.  Query caching is also case sensitive.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk You don't need units for multiplication factors. If you multiplicate a value with just a number, you get the same unit as the original value. Justin Case is a superhero that shows up only when needed (thus - just in case). The context is just "CALL get_related_articles(17232)". This call runs very close to one second, while executing the actualy query runs around 2 ms.

Comment: @3Nex How does the `$id` fit into your query? Have you actually benchmarked your query?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Forgot to say this is a line from the PHP code, so MySQL will get an actual integer

Comment: What is `n` in `ORDER BY n DESC`?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Oh god, sorry.... I removed some fields before posting the query here because there were a lot of them. I edited the query now and n is now in the field list. 

As far as benchmarking goes, Phpmyadmin told me the execution time. And as many times as i ran both, the procedure stays very close to 1 second, the query around 2 ms.

Comment: See, i realize that a variable cannot be cached, but it doesn't make sense that the procedure is 450 times slower, when the query has to be translated in BOTH cases. What is it that MAKES the procedure so much slower? I would imagine the worst case scenario should be they run the same duration.

Comment: It seems like we're missing some piece of the puzzle here. Not being able to see what the stored procedure looks like ***exactly*** makes this a guessing game.

Comment: Added the code for procedure

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk, generally stored routines are considered faster, because code is stored on the server, thus less traffic used.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the real world of MySQL!
Sometimes it's very hard to say why one query executes longer that another. But in your case the answer can be find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-operation.html):

> MySQL doesn't use cache for queries have been called from stored
>   procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive on your delay, but IN SUBSELECTS can themselves be costly.  Have you thought of doing a join to what is now your sub-select?  Also, since the articles table is basis of query, and a.id = rel.article_id, your group by on the "a.id" might be better if available via index.

```
SELECT 
      a.id, 
      a.image, 
      a.title, 
      a.excerpt, 
      a.permalink
   FROM 
      articles AS a
         JOIN category_relations AS rel 
            ON a.id = rel.article_id 
            JOIN categories AS c 
               ON rel.category_id = c.id
               AND c.type = 1
            JOIN (SELECT category_id 
                     FROM admin_category_relations 
                     WHERE article_id = {$id} ) RelByArticle
               on rel.category_id = RelByArticle.category_id
   WHERE 
      a.id != {$id}
   GROUP BY 
      a.id
   ORDER BY 
      n DESC, 
      publish_date DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: How does this answer explain OP's issue of having a slow stored procedure?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk, you are correct, but sometimes, alternate writing of queries that are better optimized for indexes can just perform better, regardless of other things going on.  SOMETIMES, its just a matter of sampling.

Comment: I think the big problem here is that the OP only needs 10 records, yet is fetching complete result sets on the joins.

Comment: Well the execution time of this query as opposed to mine is very much the same, so no improvement there. 
@AarolamaBluenk's comment, i don't know what i should change to avoid unnecessary result sets?

Comment: There's no need for derived table/inline view (the JOIN (...)) -- that can be done as INNER JOIN criteria.  But using a JOIN risks multiplying records where there's more than one child to a parent record.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Okay, but i can you tell me what exactly to change? I realized what you're saying, but i don't know enough MySQL to achieve that on my own.