# Get Warning count after Executing INSERT IGNORE using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using Java 1.7 and JDBC with MySql version 1.7.

I am executing `INSERT IGNORE` using JDBC my question is how can i get Warning count or Duplicate count after executing `INSERT IGNORE`.

I can get `INSERT` or `UPDATE` count by running :

```
Connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT IGNORE INTO Foo values (1,'Foo')")
```

Someone told me to subtract the total rows from the Update or Insert count you get from the above line. But this will mix up the duplicate and warning.

So is there any way I can these count from JDBC?

Comment: There is no such thing as MySQL version 1.7 (or maybe 20+ years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create a **procedure** that execute this Query and return what you want :

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_check (OUT param1 TEXT, f1 IN int, f2 IN VARCHAR)
BEGIN
   INSERT IGNORE INTO Foo values (f1, f2);
   -- ...return your count or your error
END
```

**CODE**

```
String query = "{call insert_check(?, ?)}"; 
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);  
statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
statement.setInt(2, 1);  
statement.setString(3, "Foo");  

statement.executeUpdate();
String countError = callableStatement.getString(1);
```

Comment: You suggestion is good but the problem is the query on which i want it to apply is executed in every two seconds so the procedure will make it slow.

Comment: mmm, how is that slow it @FazeenAhmad ?

Comment: I never used procedure but i was reading this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262397/mysql-how-come-the-procedure-is-slower-than-executing-the-query) that why i said it. May be i am wrong.

Comment: its ok good luck hope you can find the best solution, if that let me know @FazeenAhmad